# How to disable VSCode from remembering opened editors in the folder I opened before?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I use VSCode to open a folder and some editors for the files, I close the folder. When I close and reopen the folder, VSCode opens the editors I opened last time.

How to prevent VSCode from reopening the editors I opened last time?

I have already set "window.restoreWindows": "none". When I exit directly from VSCode, it won't restore windows. I am saying when I reopen a folder, the editors I opened last time before I close the folder, will still be opened.

Comment: It is very frustrating that computers tend to remember their previous state, which slows them down drastically and prevents the user from maintaining a clean slate.

Comment: new way to hide open editors https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184705#issuecomment-1584712771

Answer (score 3):

To stop Visual Studio Code from opening your previous folder all the time, then you have to edit `settings.json`.

To achieve this, open the `settings.json`. Do this by following the steps below.

1. Open the Command Palette by pressing `F1`.
2. Type, *"Open settings"*.
3. When you see the options, select *Open Settings **(JSON)***.

After that, add the following option.

```json
{
  "window.restoreWindows": "none"
}
```

This should prevent Visual Studio Code from opening the previous folder when launching the application.

Comment: Thanks, I have added this setting. But this is not what I was asking, please see the description I added.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. I will try and find another solution (or you can use the other solutions).

Comment: This option is `none` for me and it still remembers file tabs

Comment: I don't know then...

Answer (score 0):

Follow this process

Open VS Code, goto    file>preferences>settings.
search for    restore Window    or click on    Window    tab then find   restore window  .select   none  from selection.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLx4a.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAuHT.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8W5a.png

Comment: Thanks, I have added this setting. But this is not what I was asking, please see the description I added.

Comment: If I am not wrong probably you were asking about something like,
you open folder A , then you open folder B , and you exit vs code, then restart, it will restore folder B, you want folder A to be opened right?

Comment: Not really. When I open folder A and open some editors for files in that folder, then close folder A, open folder A again, the file editors I opened previously will still show up. How to let VSCode forget what editors I opened for folder A?

Comment: your vs code don't have access to other editors, I think you can't do it, but if you want your file manager to open folder always in vs code, you can set as default

Comment: The editors I meant were the tabs you open for files in VSCode.

Comment: means you want to close all editor tabs, and keep the editor area blank, but it will still have folder A as workplace in Vs code. let me write another answer

Comment: I did't found any way to close opened editor, you may research a litle bit of settings json customization, there could be a way I hope inshaAllah